# Is GCM jar Works after 11th April, 2019?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Currently our Android application is using GCM jar. For some reasons, we are not going to migrate to FCM for our client app. Upon 11th April, 2019, is GCM still work in our client side given our server side has migrated to FCM?

To emphasis, the application is using GCM.jar which is rather old (still using GCMRegistrar, GCMBaseIntentService & GCMBroadcastReceiver), and the targetSDKVersion is 23. And the google play services is 9.0.0 (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0)

p.s.
I cannot find information about the old version of GCM. I found this info: “Both GCM sdk and FCM sdk use Google Play services to create tokens and receive messages. Google Play services is not being deprecated. GCM sdk is being deprecated in favor of the FCM sdk. In this context deprecated means: 
- already released versions of the GCM sdk will keep working 
- GCM sdk will not receive updates, bugfixes or support 
- if future versions of Android will introduce breaking changes, the GCM sdk will NOT receive the necessary updates and therefore will not work on the new devices.

On the Server side, the GCM endpoint is being deprecated in favor of the FCM endpoint. 
- the FCM endpoint supports GCM token 
- we plan to disable the GCM endpoint in the future”

Yet how about the old GCM version?

Answer (score 0):

The GCM API client and server endpoints were removed some time in 2019, and according to the [GCM and FCM FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) (now removed), calls to these endpoints should now be expected to fail.

Previously, the FAQ stated:

> Note that client SDKs and GCM tokens will continue to work. However, the GCM Android client SDK will stop working if your app targets android versions later than Q.

Meaning that as long as your server-side has been updated to use FCM, your client app should be fine, as long as you don't target Android Q.

Comment: By "indefinitely", does it means forever or uncertain? Since from the paragraph, it seems to suggest the former one (Note "However").

Comment: By definition, indefinitely means "an unspecified period of time". Could be 10 years, could be next week. The only ones that would know that are Google themselves.